# Unable to "git stash pop" due to conflict

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, git

I have a local git repository and had several modified files. Then I needed to quickly produce a fix for something so I

- stashed my changes (git stash)
- edited file (vi file)
- committed (git commit)
- popped stash (git stash pop)

This resulted in Conflict.

```
# On branch master
$ git stash pop
Auto-merging page/search.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in page/search.php
$ git status
# On branch master
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      page/search.php
```

If I try to cleanup the changes and re-apply stash, the same thing happens (conflict). I do not care much about the page/search.php, but I would like to get other files out from the stash.

Is there a way to convert stash into a patch or simply get the files as they were when stashed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The stash has already been applied to other files; it is only `page/search.php` that you have to merge manually. Afterwards just run `git reset` to unstage the changes and keep on hacking – or `git add ...` and commit.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. After i recovered the patch with -p, I found out that other files are already updated.

Comment: very nice, `git stash pop`, resolve your conflicts then `git add x` then `git reset` to get it out of staging, Thanks!

Comment: @Quang There should be a `stash pop --continue` which aliases to `reset`. :)

Answer (score 15):

Resolved with:

```
git stash show -p
```

Comment: That saved my day, =)

Comment: Does `-p` do anything here?

Comment: show? -p ? what this does? how "show" could be related to resolve conflicts?

Comment: This command shows the changes made in the stash, allowing you to manually merge

Comment: I found ```git stash show -p | git apply && git stash drop``` from https://coderwall.com/p/anxp0g/force-a-git-stash-pop, and I'm trying to verify it will work before I run it. :-)

Answer (score 9):

After the `git stash pop` command, you then have to resolve the conflict by hand then do `git stash drop` manually as the `man git-stash` suggests.